# Is there a way to have selenium only give me todays data?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to create a script that tells me the tide leveles of the day using `selenium` but it gives me all the data for the entire week. How do i have it only give me todays data?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time
import datetime
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/judeslater/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://magicseaweed.com/Nosara-Surf-Report/445/Tide/')


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]')))


Day_of_Week = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

Break_Key = Day_of_Week + 1

element = driver.find_elements_by_id('msw-js-tide-list')

intDay = datetime.date(year=2000, month=12, day=1).weekday()
days = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"]

def contains_word(string, target):
    return target in string

   

for value in element:
    Ocean_Data = value
    print(Ocean_Data.text)
    time.sleep(1)
    if contains_word(str(Ocean_Data), days[Break_Key]) == True:
       break
    else:
        continue
    break
    

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Do you want the filtering done on selenium side, or on python's?

Comment: whichever way works

Comment: Just use filter() on the element then

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: maybe you should use `print()` inside `if` to display only one element.

Comment: I don't understand why to create `contains_word` only to check `target in string` - it would be more readable to use it directly `if days[Break_Key] in str(Ocean_Data):`. You could also use `print( days[Break_Key], str(Ocean_Data) )` to see what you compare - maybe you compare different values then you expect and maybe this makes problem.

Comment: if you need only first element then you could use `element[0]` or you could use `find_element_by_id('msw-js-tide-list')` without char `s` in word `element` to get only first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many mistakes but main is your

```
find_elements_by_id('msw-js-tide-list')
```

which gives you table with all days as one element.

You should use more complex `xpath` with `/div` at the end to get every day as separated element - and then you can filter it.

```
find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]/div')
```

---

You don't have to add `+1` to `Day_of_Week` because `python` start indexing at `0`

If you want to get tomorrow day then better use

```
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

or use modulo to move to `0` when you get `7`

```
Break_Key = (Day_of_Week + 1) % 7
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time
import datetime

days = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"]

today = datetime.datetime.today()
#tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#day_of_week = tomorrow.weekday()
day_of_week = today.weekday()
selected_day = days[day_of_week]


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/judeslater/Downloads/chromedriver')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://magicseaweed.com/Nosara-Surf-Report/445/Tide/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]')))

all_days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]/div')

for ocean_data in all_days:
    if selected_day in ocean_data.text:
        print(ocean_data.text)
        break

driver.quit()
```

---

If you want today's data then probably it will be always as first day in table so you could use `all_days[1]` without checking `selected_day`

There is hidden `div` in HTML so I have to use `[1]` instead of `[0]` to get today's data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/judeslater/Downloads/chromedriver')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://magicseaweed.com/Nosara-Surf-Report/445/Tide/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]')))

all_days = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]/div')

ocean_data = all_days[1] # there is one hidden `div` which I have to skip to get today's data
print(ocean_data.text)

driver.quit()
```

---

I can do the same using `[2]` in `xpath` (because `python` start indexing at `0` but `xpath` starts at `1`) and using `find_element_...` without char `s` in word `element` to get only one result

```
ocean_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]/div[2]')
print(ocean_data.text)
```

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
import time
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/judeslater/Downloads/chromedriver')
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://magicseaweed.com/Nosara-Surf-Report/445/Tide/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]')))

ocean_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="msw-js-tide-list"]/div[2]')
print(ocean_data.text)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for value in element:
```

Instead of this for loop why not just use element[0] since you only need the first element of that list ('msw-js-tide-list') which gives today's date.

```
Ocean_Data = element[0]
print(Ocean_Data.text)
time.sleep(1)
if contains_word(str(Ocean_Data), days[Break_Key]) == True:
   break
```